# responseTime is not working in Mockjax

Tags: javascript, ajax, casperjs, mockjax

I need to simulate a long responseTime. My Moockjax is working – it delivers the right mock data. But my ajax call is done in the second i load the page, even if i set the responseTime to 20 seconds.

Do you have an idea?

I reduced my test page to the minimum, to exclude other potential sources of error here:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../jquery.mockjax.js"></script>
    <title>MockJax Tests</title>
  </head>
<body>
    <h1>A MockJax test.</h1>
    <p>Take a look into the console.</p>
    <script>

        $.mockjax({
          url: "foo.html",
          responseTime: 20000,
          responseText: "Hi! I am mockjax."
        });

        $.ajax({
          async: false,
          url: 'foo.html',
          success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
          },
          error:function(data){
            console.log('It doesn’t work that way :(');
          }
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I also wrote a test with CasperJS and Mockjax (inside of casper.evaluate). It is the same there.

Here is my CasperJS code

```
var casper = require("casper").create({
  verbose: true,
  logLevel: 'error',
  clientScripts: ["node_modules/jquery-mockjax/jquery.mockjax.js"]
});

casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
  this.echo('remote message caught: ' + msg);
})

casper.start('http://der-zyklop.de/', function() {
  this.evaluate(function () {

    $.mockjax({
      url: "/blog/feed",
      responseTime: 20000,
      responseText: "Hi! I am mockjax!"
    });

    $.ajax({
      async: false,
      url: '/blog/feed',
      success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
      },
      error:function(data){
        console.log('It doesn’t work that way :(');
      }
    });

  });
});

casper.run();
```

If you have CasperJS installed, you should be able to run it by `npm install jquery-mockjax` and then `casperjs test.js`. It gives me this output in **under** 20 seconds:

[image: mockjax output]

I also wrote a blogarticle about it [here](http://der-zyklop.de/blog/casperjs-with-mockjax).

Comment: What jQuery version are you using? If you're using 2.x you can try downgrading to 1.x

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I tried it now with 1.11.1 and 2.1.1. Unfortunately nothing changes.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Sure. No problem. I added the content of my CasperJS test-file.

Comment: FYI, I've added an [issue in Github](https://github.com/jakerella/jquery-mockjax/issues/210) to address this - either by implementing it natively or documenting how to do it with the code we have now.

Answer (score 2):

Mockjax is currently not capable of doing a blocking delay. See the [current code](https://github.com/jakerella/jquery-mockjax/blob/e4969fd891a50f259e65a2f61a646038d773f2c1/jquery.mockjax.js#L242-L247):

```
if ( requestSettings.async === false ) {
    // TODO: Blocking delay
    process();
} else {
    this.responseTimer = setTimeout(process, parseResponseTimeOpt(mockHandler.responseTime) || 50);
}
```

You will need to specify `async: true` for this to work. When you do, you will need to wait in the casper context, because the control flow would continue without waiting for the result.

```
casper.start(url, yourEvaluateFunction).wait(25000).run();
```

I don't think, a blocking delay is even possible with JavaScript besides somehow doing a busywait. But during this time everything else will also stand still (JavaScript is single-threaded) and you won't gain anything from the busywait.

Comment: Yeah, that TODO has been there a LONG time. Before I took over the code. Honestly, I don't see a need for it give the alternate solution I suggested, but... I'm open to it.

Comment: let's continue the discussion on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, @artjom-b is correct. We haven't implemented `responseTime` for non-async requests because there really isn't a reason to in terms of code execution (that is, the ajax request will not be async in any case, so why the delay?). That said, you could implement a `response` function (instead of using `responseText`) and then force a delay using a simple setTimeout() and our new [async response functionality](https://github.com/jakerella/jquery-mockjax/pull/186):

```
$.mockjax({
  url: 'foo.html',
  response: function(settings, done) {  // the "done" argument makes this async
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
      self.responseText = "Hi! I am mockjax.";
      done();   // this ends the async action
    }, 20000);  // here is your 20 second delay
  }
});
```

**NOTE: You will need to be using Mockjax 1.6.0 or later to get this functionality!**

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Mockjax? This was only introduced in v1.6.0, which hasn't been out long. The async functionality does work (both in our own tests and in my code).

Comment: ;) No worries... its' a new feature!